# offline font converter for @font-face

Tags: css, font-face, converters

Is there any **free and offline** font converter which can convert
.ttf(truetype) format to

- .eot
- .woff
- .svg

Want to use in `@font-face` likes,

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyFontFace';
src: url('fonts/MyFont.eot');
src: local('☺'), url('fonts/MyFont.woff') format('woff'),  
    url('fonts/MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/MyFont.svg')        
    format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
           }
```

Comment: go to http://www.fontlab.com/ they have plenty of tools for download

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to an offline converter? FontSquirrel has a great online one.

Answer (score 5):

If you have [fontforge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) you can use it convert ttf to svg and woff. [ttf2eot](https://code.google.com/p/ttf2eot/) tool can convert to eot. These two are offline tools that should satisfy your offline requirements.

But as ralph.m suggested you are better off using one of the online converters. Fontsquirrel is one. Everything Fonts has a font-face converter too.

http://everythingfonts.com/font-face